# Created a symbolic link on a linux system - can't access it on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, symbolic-link

got the following problem.

We have a small homeserver running OpenMediaVault, which is used (among other things) to backup our Windows PC stuff onto.

Now I would like to share a subfolder of my personal backup files with my wife, she is not supposed to see the root folders though.

Example: /myPCBackup/Documents/folderForTheWife

She is supposed to access the "folderForTheWife", but not the entire "Documents" folder.

On the homeserver, I created a SMB shared folder for the wife to later access. I ssh'd into the homeserver and in the new shared folder used the "ln -s /myPCBackup/Documents/folderForTheWife" command to create a symbolic link.
The link shows up in the folder and I can access the folder and all subfolders correctly with the root account, my personal account, and my wife's account through linux ssh access.
However, when I try to access the new symbolic link folder with Windows Explorer on Windows 10, I get an access denied error, even when I use my personal user account. If I navigate to the actual folder through (not through the symbolic link) I can access it no problem.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I access the symbolic link folder through Windows Explorer?

Comment: Windows uses SMB. Linux uses Samba to serve files to windows over SMB. Samba is the problem. See here: https://blusmurf.net/2014/06/samba-access-denied-error-when-accessing-symlink-paths/

Comment: Hey Appleoddity,

thank you for your reply!

I checked the link and tried the modifications. Unfortunately, it didn't help. Problem still persists.
"follow symlinks" and "unix extensions" was already set to "yes", only had to change "wide links" to yes. Restarted the Samba service. But like mentioned above, still the same error on Windows Explorer. :(

Comment: Played around a bit more with it.
Using "allow insecure wide links = yes" seems to have fixed the problem!! See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path/137192#137192